# Python interprer closes after reciving input

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and tried doing what i did when I was starting with C++. Making  simple calculator, the thing is that while the code builds just right, when I'm running the code, the window closes as soon as it recives input.

```
print("Calculadora version 1.0")
print("""Operaciones disponibles:
    -Suma
    -Resta
    -Division
    -Multiplicacion
    -Radicacion
    -Potenciacion
    -Exponenciacion""")
selec_op = input("La operacion que selecciono es: ")
op_list = ["Suma","Resta","Division","Multiplicacion","Radicacion","Potenciacion","Exponenciacion"]

if selec_op==1:
    print("Operacion elegida",op_list[selec_op])
    num1 = float(input("Escriba el primer numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escriba el segundo numero: "))
    result = str(num1 + num2)
    print(result)
```

Comment: "the window", can I guess that you double-click the `.py` file, it opens up a console/terminal window, runs your program, then immediately closes? If so then that is entirely understandable, your program has terminated, and if your terminal application of choice does not, by itself, wait for the user to close the window but instead just closes on its own then that is what is going to happen. This is the default behavior on Windows, unsure what is default on other operating systems.

Comment: You should also probably wrap your `selec_op` with `int()` when comparing to 1: `if int(selec_op)==1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your if statement you are comparing `str` and `int` which will never be equal. You should cast `str` to `int`.

```
print("Calculadora version 1.0")
print("""Operaciones disponibles:
    -Suma
    -Resta
    -Division
    -Multiplicacion
    -Radicacion
    -Potenciacion
    -Exponenciacion""")
selec_op = int(input("La operacion que selecciono es: ")) #cast here in order not to cast in other places
op_list = ["Suma","Resta","Division","Multiplicacion","Radicacion","Potenciacion","Exponenciacion"]

if selec_op==1:
    print("Operacion elegida",op_list[selec_op])
    num1 = float(input("Escriba el primer numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escriba el segundo numero: "))
    result = str(num1 + num2)
    print(result)
```